# How to use torchvision.transforms for data augmentation of segmentation task in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformation, torchvision

I am a little bit confused about the data augmentation performed in PyTorch.

Because we are dealing with segmentation tasks, we need data and mask for the same data augmentation, but some of them are random, such as random rotation.

Keras provides a `random seed` guarantee that data and mask do the same operation, as shown in the following code:

```
    data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                         featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                         rotation_range=25,
                         horizontal_flip=True,
                         vertical_flip=True)


    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    seed = 1
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow(train_data, seed=seed, batch_size=1)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(train_label, seed=seed, batch_size=1)

    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

I didn't find a similar description in the official Pytorch documentation, so I don't know how to ensure that data and mask can be processed synchronously.

Pytorch does provide such a function, but I want to apply it to a custom Dataloader.

For example：

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    img = np.zeros((self.im_ht, self.im_wd, channel_size))
    mask = np.zeros((self.im_ht, self.im_wd, channel_size))

    temp_img = np.load(Image_path + '{:0>4}'.format(self.patient_index[index]) + '.npy')
    temp_label = np.load(Label_path + '{:0>4}'.format(self.patient_index[index]) + '.npy')

    for i in range(channel_size):
        img[:,:,i] = temp_img[self.count[index] + i]
        mask[:,:,i] = temp_label[self.count[index] + i]

    if self.transforms:
        img = np.uint8(img)
        mask = np.uint8(mask)
        img = self.transforms(img)
        mask = self.transforms(mask)

    return img, mask
```

In this case, img and mask will be transformed separately, because some operations such as random rotation are random, so the correspondence between mask and image may be changed. In other words, the image may have rotated but the mask did not do this.

## EDIT 1

I used the method in [augmentations.py](https://github.com/a514514772/DISE-Domain-Invariant-Structure-Extraction/blob/master/util/loader/augmentations.py), but I got an error:：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_transform.py", line 87, in <module>
    for batch_idx, image, mask in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "/home/dirk/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 314, in __next__
    batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
  File "/home/dirk/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 314, in <listcomp>
    batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
  File "/home/dirk/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py", line 103, in __getitem__
    return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
  File "/home/dirk/home/data/dirk/segmentation_unet_pytorch/data.py", line 164, in __getitem__
    img, mask = self.transforms(img, mask)
  File "/home/dirk/home/data/dirk/segmentation_unet_pytorch/augmentations.py", line 17, in __call__
    img, mask = a(img, mask)
TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

This is my code for `__getitem__()`：

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': Compose([
        RandomHorizontallyFlip(),
        RandomRotate(degree=25),
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ]),
}

train_set = DatasetUnetForTestTransform(fold=args.fold, random_index=args.random_index,transforms=data_transforms['train'])

# __getitem__ in class DatasetUnetForTestTransform
def __getitem__(self, index):
    img = np.zeros((self.im_ht, self.im_wd, channel_size))
    mask = np.zeros((self.im_ht, self.im_wd, channel_size))
    temp_img = np.load(Label_path + '{:0>4}'.format(self.patient_index[index]) + '.npy')
    temp_label = np.load(Label_path + '{:0>4}'.format(self.patient_index[index]) + '.npy')
    temp_img, temp_label = crop_data_label_from_0(temp_img, temp_label)
    for i in range(channel_size):
        img[:,:,i] = temp_img[self.count[index] + i]
        mask[:,:,i] = temp_label[self.count[index] + i]

    if self.transforms:
        img = T.ToPILImage()(np.uint8(img))
        mask = T.ToPILImage()(np.uint8(mask))
        img, mask = self.transforms(img, mask)

    img = T.ToTensor()(img).copy()
    mask = T.ToTensor()(mask).copy()
    return img, mask
```

## EDIT 2

I found that after ToTensor, the dice between the same labels becomes 255 instead of 1, how to fix it?

```
# Dice computation
def DSC_computation(label, pred):
    pred_sum = pred.sum()
    label_sum = label.sum()
    inter_sum = np.logical_and(pred, label).sum()
    return 2 * float(inter_sum) / (pred_sum + label_sum)
```

Feel free to ask if more code is needed to explain the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`torchvision` also provides similar functions [[document]](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision-transforms).

Here is a simple example,

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.CenterCrop((178, 178)),
                                    transforms.Resize(128),
                                    transforms.RandomRotation(20),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
dset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(data_root, transforms=trans)
```

---

## EDIT

A brief example when customizing your own CelebA dataset. Note that, to apply transformations, you need call `transform` list in `__getitem__`.

```
class CelebADataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transforms=None, num=None):
        super(CelebADataset, self).__init__()

        self.img_root = os.path.join(root, 'img_align_celeba')
        self.attr_root = os.path.join(root, 'Anno/list_attr_celeba.txt')
        self.transforms = transforms

        df = pd.read_csv(self.attr_root, sep='\s+', header=1, index_col=0)
        #print(df.columns.tolist())
        if num is None:
            self.labels = df.values
            self.img_name = df.index.values
        else:
            self.labels = df.values[:num]
            self.img_name = df.index.values[:num]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.img_root, self.img_name[index]))
        # only use blond_hair, eyeglass, male, smile
        indices = [9, 15, 20, 31]
        label = np.take(self.labels[index], indices)
        label[label==-1] = 0

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img = self.transforms(img)

        return np.asarray(img), label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

---

## EDIT 2

I probably miss something at the first glance. The main point of your problem is how to apply "the same" data preprocessing to img and labels. To my understanding, there is no available Pytorch built-in function. So, what I did before is to implement the augmentation by myself.

```
class RandomRotate(object):
    def __init__(self, degree):
        self.degree = degree

    def __call__(self, img, mask):
        rotate_degree = random.random() * 2 * self.degree - self.degree
        return img.rotate(rotate_degree, Image.BILINEAR), 
                           mask.rotate(rotate_degree, Image.NEAREST)
```

Note that the input should be PIL format. See [this](https://github.com/a514514772/DISE-Domain-Invariant-Structure-Extraction/blob/master/util/loader/augmentations.py) for more information.

Comment: I re-edited my question. Your example is for classification tasks. How to modify it if used to segmentation tasks? 

Specifically, we need to rotate the image and label at the same time, so how should we guarantee their correspondence here? 

If use 

```img, label = self.transforms(img), self.transforms(label)```

the random rotation in transforms will break the correspondence between image and label.  In other words, the image may have rotated but the mask did not do this.

Comment: @Dirk Li, thanks for your comment. I've added how I deal with it before.

Comment: I used the method in `augmentations.py`, but there was an error. And I added a description of the error in the problem description.

Comment: My fault. Please use the `Compose` in augmentation.py. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am now aware of the cause of the problem. But there is another place that confuses me. I use `labe1, label2 = self.transforms(label,label)` to test if transform changed the data.I calculate Dice with label1 and label2 and the result is 255 (previously 1). I know that ToTensor will divide the data by 255, but I still don't understand why Dice becomes 255 and how to fix it. By the way, random_rotation in augmentations will reduce Dice to 244. Does this mean that it changes the correspondence? Dice computation is added to the question description.

Comment: Do you want to compute intersection over union in your so-called dice? I am confused why you sum up all pixel values by ```pred_sum = pred.sum()
    label_sum = label.sum()```

Comment: Because according to the definition of DSC: DSC(a,b)=2*(a & b)/(|a|+|b|), we need to calculate the area of the mask.

Comment: I could be wrong and am not sure about the format of your `pred` and `label`, but it seems to me that you need to convert the `pred` and `label` to be binary masks first, like `(pred>0.5).sum()` if `pred` is probability or using `pred.size(2)*pred.size(3)` as |a|.

Comment: Soory, this is my fault, I omitted this step in the description. The final result was obtained after binarization.

Answer (score 5):

Transforms which require input parameters like `RandomCrop` has a `get_param` method which would return the parameters for that particular transformation. This can be then applied to both the image and mask using the functional interface of transforms:

```
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

i, j, h, w = transforms.RandomCrop.get_params(input, (100, 100))
input = F.crop(input, i, j, h, w)
target = F.crop(target, i, j, h, w)
```

Sample available here:
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.2.0

Complete example available here for VOC & COCO:
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/segmentation/transforms.py
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/segmentation/train.py

Regarding the error,

`ToTensor()` was not overridden to handle additional mask argument, so it cannot be in `data_transforms`. Moreover, `__getitem__` does `ToTensor` of both `img` and `mask` before returning them.

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': Compose([
        RandomHorizontallyFlip(),
        RandomRotate(degree=25),
        #transforms.ToTensor()  => remove this line
    ]),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to stack your image and mask along the channel dimensions and then transform them together. Obviously this only works for geometric-type transforms and you need to use the same dtype for both. I use something like this:

```
# Apply these to image and mask
affine_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=180),
    ...
])

# Apply these to image only
image_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.GaussianBlur(),
    ...
])

# Loader...
def __getitem__(self, index: int):
    # Get the image and mask, here shape=(HxW) for both
    image = self.images[index]
    mask = self.masks[index]

    # Stack the image and mask together so they get the same geometric transformations
    stacked = torch.cat([image, mask], dim=0)  # shape=(2xHxW)
    stacked = self.affine_transforms(stacked)

    # Split them back up again
    image, mask = torch.chunk(stacked, chunks=2, dim=0)

    # Image transforms are only applied to the image
    image = self.image_transforms(image)

    return image, mask
```