# TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. To train Raccoon prediction model using FastRCNN through Transfer Learning

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

```
 from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
 from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
 import utils
 import torchvision.transforms as T

 num_epochs = 10
 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    lr_scheduler.step()
    evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
```

I am using the same code as provided in this link [Building Raccoon Model](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae) but mine is not working.

This is the error message I am getting
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
  2 for epoch in range(num_epochs):

  3    # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations

  4   ----> train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)

  5     # update the learning rate

  6   lr_scheduler.step()
```

7 frames

in **getitem**(self, idx)

```
 29         target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

 30         if self.transforms is not None:

 31        ---> img, target = self.transforms(img, target)

 32         return img, target
 33
```

TypeError: **call**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: same here trying to modify a simple transform for images: " __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it looks like this problem is related to the version of Pytorch or torchvision

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is incorrect, I accidentally upvoted before noticing. You are using the wrong Compose, note that it says

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html#putting-everything-together

"In references/detection/, we have a number of helper functions to simplify training and evaluating detection models. Here, we will use references/detection/engine.py, references/detection/utils.py and references/detection/transforms.py. Just copy them to your folder and use them here."

there are helper scripts. They subclass the compose and flip methods

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/6315358dd06e3a2bcbe9c1e8cdaa10898ac2b308/references/detection/transforms.py#L17

I did the same thing before noticing this. Do not use the compose method from torchvision.transforms, or else you will get the error above. Download their module and load it.

Comment: This solution will work on Linux computers, but you can't install their module on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of a newbie at this and I was also having the same problem.

Upon doing more research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215056/how-to-use-torchvision-transforms-for-data-augmentation-of-segmentation-task-in) where the accepted answer used:

```
img = self.transforms(img)
```

instead of:

```
img, target = self.transforms(img, target)
```

Removing "target" solved the error for me and should solve it for you as well. Not entirely sure why even the official PyTorch [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html#defining-the-dataset) also has "target" included but it does not work for us.

Comment: This is dangerous! The problem is that if you transform your image, but not your boxes, you will get a mismatch, imagine you inverted one and not the other. I think this is not the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes this makes sense especially if the transform is positional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there is even an issue raised on Pytorch discussion forum using regarding the same [T.Compose | TypeError: **call**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/t-compose-typeerror-call-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given/62529)

I was able to overcome this issue by `copy` and `pasting` the files on the for a specific version [v0.3.0](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/v0.3.0/references/detection) on the `vision/reference/detection` of the tutorial I am following [building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae)

Just to fall into another issue I have raised here [ValueError: All bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invaid box [500.728515625, 533.3333129882812, 231.10546875, 255.2083282470703] for target at index 0. #2740](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/2740?#issuecomment-1112877295)